# JavaScript reduce inner array of array and create answer array

Tags: javascript, arrays, reduce

Array of arrays:

```
list = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]];
```

I want to reduce (combine) each inner array (1+2+3) and (4+5+6) and then put those results 6 and 15 in their own array like `[6, 15]`.

I have below code:

```
list.reduce((a, b) => a + b);
```

but it's just strangely combining everything in all the arrays.

Answer (score 2):

You need to iterate both the outer and the inner arrays.

```
list.map(array => array.reduce((a, b) => a + b))
```

Answer (score 2):

**You can do it like this**

`map()` with map we iterate on every element of arr.

`reduce()` - with reduce we reduce each element to a single value.

```js
let arr = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6]];
let op = arr.map(e => e.reduce( (a, b) => a + b, 0) );
console.log(op);
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `.map()` with `.reduce()`:

```js
let list = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]];
let reducer = (a, b) => (a + b);

let result = list.map(arr => arr.reduce(reducer));

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also achieve this with [`Array.from`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) since its second parameter is [`Array.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) function and inside you can do your [`Array.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) for the summation:

```js
const data = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]

const result = Array.from(data, x => x.reduce((r,c) => r+c))

console.log(result)
```